# Django Filtering A Blog Based on Tags

Tags: django

I'm trying to filter my blog based on tags. I've managed to work out how to display all the tags, however now I want the user to have the ability to click on a tag and bring up a filter list of blog posts based on that tag.

I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'testtag'
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples: /blogs
    url(r'^tags$', 'blog.views.tags', name='tags'),
    url(r'^tags/(?P<blog_tagslug>[\w-]+)$', 'blog.views.tagslist', name='tagslist'),
```

views.py

```
def tags(request):
    blog_obj = Tag.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(blog_obj, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        blog_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        blog_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        blog_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    template_hash = {'blog_list':blog_list}
    return render(request,'blog/tags.html', template_hash)

def tagslist(request, blog_tagslug):
    #blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    #blog = Tag.objects.all().filter(tagslug=blog_tagslug)
    blog = Blog.objects.all().filter(tags=blog_tagslug)

    paginator = Paginator(blog, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        blog_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        blog_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        blog_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    template_hash = {'blog_list':blog_list}
    return render(request,'blog/index.html', template_hash)
```

tags.html (works fine)

```
<h1>All Tags</h1>
{% if blog_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for blog in blog_list %}
        {{ blog.image.thumbnail.url }}

        <li><a href="{% url "tagslist" blog.tagslug %}">{{ blog.tagslug }}</a></li>
        {{ blog.tags.all|join:", " }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No blogs are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if blog_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ blog_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ blog_list.number }} of {{ blog_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if blog_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ blog_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

tagslist.html (doesn't work gets error)

```
<h1>Blog Index</h1>
{% if blog_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for blog in blog_list %}
        {{ blog.image.thumbnail.url }}

        <li><a href="{% url "show" blog.id blog.slug %}">{{ blog.blog_title }}</a></li>
        {{ blog.tags.all|join:", " }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No blogs are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if blog_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ blog_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ blog_list.number }} of {{ blog_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if blog_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ blog_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Image(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
     thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
    tagslug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tagslug

class Author(models.Model):
    authorname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.authorname


class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)    
    blog_content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  
    blog_id = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}, {1}'.format(self.comment_content, self.created)
```

Comment: @ozgur it looked like this http://localhost:8000/blogs/tags/testtag, ie http://localhost:8000/blogs/tags/ *insert tag here*. However the tagslist.html doesn't filter out the tag variable and display just the results of every blog which has that tag attached to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tags` expect a list of `Tag` objects whereas you pass a string. You should filter blogs by tag's slug as follows:

```
blog = Blog.objects.all().filter(tags__tagslug=blog_tagslug)
```

Comment: This worked a treat. Thanks so much really appreciate it. I always seem to get really confused around the django orm. I come from a sql background, so still adjusting. Thanks again