# How to filter Charfiled by List of Tags in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the preferred way to filter CharField using List of Tags? 
in database i have something like this :

genres = "something, apple ,something_else ,something_else2, orange, grape, more.."

i tried using `__in` operator nothing comes out

```
elem = list(Elements.objects.filter(genres__in=['apple','orange','grape']))
```

Comment: In character filed you store tags like a single string. But `__in` works with list of objects.

Comment: so what i need to do ? Shafikur Rahman

Comment: The better solution for tags is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632947/django-filtering-a-blog-based-on-tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get what i want doing the following:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

tag_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']

query = reduce(and_, (Q(genres__icontains=tag) for tag in tag_list))
elem = list(Elements.objects.filter(query))
```

You can also use `or_` operator see:

[How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852414/how-to-dynamically-compose-an-or-query-filter-in-django)'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
elem = list(Elements.objects.filter(Q(genres__icontains="apple") | Q(genres__icontains="orange") | Q(genres__icontains="grape")))
```

But I think for tags it's a better solution [Django Filtering A Blog Based on Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632947/django-filtering-a-blog-based-on-tags)

Comment: just changed OR "|" with AND "&" thank you Shafikur Rahman you are life saver, but i wonder how can achieve this in one line of code because i have like 30 tag to filter ^_^

Answer (score -1):

You would probably want to use a Q lookup. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
from django.db.models import Q

elem = Elements.objects.filter(Q(genres__icontains="apple") | Q(genres__icontains="orange") | Q(genres__icontains="grapes"))
```